# VideoJS how to increase buffer-sizes?

Tags: streaming, http-live-streaming, video.js

Im trying to play a HLS using VideoJS. Basically the stream itself is working fine but it seems that the buffer size is to small and the video lags every couple of seconds/minutes for 1-2 sec. Is there any way to increase the actual size of segemnts preloaded? Currently I have VideoJS implemented like so:

```
...
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="player-center">
                    <video-js autoplay id=player class="vjs-fluid" controls="true">
                        <source src="{{ playlist_url }}" type="application/x-mpegURL">
                    </video-js>
                    <script src="{% static 'videojs_old/video.js' %}"></script>
                    <script src="{% static 'videojs_old/videojs-http-streaming.js' %}"></script>
                    <script>
                        videojs.Vhs.xhr.beforeRequest = function(options) {
                        options.headers = options.headers || {};
                        options.headers.Authorization = "{{ access_token }}";

                        console.log('options', options)
                        return options;
                        };
                        var player = videojs('player',
                            {fill: false},
                            {autoplay: true},
                            {responsive: true},
                            {fluid: true},
                            {GOAL_BUFFER_LENGTH: 100},
                            {CMAX_GOAL_BUFFER_LENGTH: 150},
                            {preload: "auto"});
                        player.play();
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But it seems that GOAL_BUFFER_LENGTH nor CMAX_GOAL_BUFFER_LENGTH has any effect.

Answer (score 0):

The constants are not player level options. Also you can pass only one options object.

```js
videojs.Vhs.GOAL_BUFFER_LENGTH = 100;
videojs.Vhs.MAX_GOAL_BUFFER_LENGTH = 150;
var player = videojs('player', {
  fill: false,
  autoplay: true,
  responsive: true,
  fluid: true,
  preload: "auto"
});
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that your Browser will tell you the following: VIDEOJS: WARN: using Vhs.GOAL_BUFFER_LENGTH is UNSAFE be sure you know what you are doing. Not sure whats going on in the background

Comment: Please what's the default buffer size? and is this in seconds or milliseconds